# Laravel4: How can I use Eloquent/Model

Tags: php, laravel

I've read and followed documentation found here http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent
and I tried some of the examples i found here 
here is the code that I have so far
model

**dbeloquent.php**

```
<?php
class dbeloquent extends Eloquent {

   protected  $table = "users";


    public  function showTbl()
        {
             dd(dbeloquent::$table);
        }
}

//end of model
?>

    route.php

<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    $model = new dbeloquent();   
    dd($model->someFunction());
});
?>
```

I want to show my tables first but here is what I'm having

> Access to undeclared static property: dbeloquent::$table

somebody help me please

Comment: `public  function showTbl()
        {
             dd($this->table);
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **dbeloquent** class is extending **Model** class in the background. Eloquent alias is pointing to Model class, in the **app/config/app.php** file

'Eloquent' => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model'

**protected $table** property is extended from the abstract **Model** class, and it is not static, so you can't redeclare it (static or nostatic) .The way you can access property from base model is by using:

```
__get($key) method
```

But the problem is in which point of execution your **$table** property is visible, since it is protected and modified at run time.

At the end, it is not declared and defined to be used in such a way - Laravel is internally looking for that property. Try to trace calls, and you will probably find what is happening inside.
Don't complicate things more then they should be complicated.

Comment: sorry sir @carousel this is my 1st time handling a php frameworks.. so please bear with my stupid questions.. but how do I trace calls?

Comment: No problem - we were all at the beginning. You can easily trace function calls with PHP debugger (XDebug is pretty popular),depending on Editor/IDE that you use. Check if it has support for PHP debugging. I am using Vim with Vdebug. And please accept answer :)

Comment: Ok I will try it today.. and get back to you as soon as I get the result